# Failure in multiple times Parameters Passing in Django (Python)

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. My current plan is displaying user name on different html pages, once user have successfully logged in. At the moment, the page after login page can successfully display the user name with the django tag in html which is {{ username }}. But once it has successfully passed to my second page, my second page CAN NOT pass it to my third page. The attached images are my html codes for second.html and third.html. Thanks for your help.

## Second.html

```
 <form action="/SecondPageSub/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}<br>
    <b>NTID:</b><br>
    <label name="usrnm">{{username}}</label>
    <button type="submit" name="SecondPageSub">
    SUBMIT
    </button>
</form>
```

## Third.html

```
     <form action="/ThirdPageSub/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}<br>
        <b>NTID:</b><br>
        <label name="usrnm">{{username}}</label>
        <button type="submit" name="ThirdPageSub">
        SUBMIT
        </button>
    </form>
```

## Python codes in view.py

```
    def ActionGet(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            if 'login' in request.POST:
                usrname = request.POST.get("usrnm", None)
                passwrd = request.POST.get("pwd", None)
                dic={}
                dic['username']=usrname
                dic['password']=passwrd
                return render(request, "Second.html",dic)

            if 'SecondPageSub' in request.POST:
                usrname = request.POST.get("usrnm", None)
                dic={}
                dic['username']=usrname
                return render(request, "Third.html",dic)

            if 'ThirdPageSub' in request.POST:
                usrname = request.POST.get("usrnm", None)
                dic={}
                dic['username']=usrname
                return render(request, "Forth.html",dic)
```

Comment: Please post code instead of screenshots.

Comment: What do your urls look like?

Comment: I have attached html code instead of screenshots. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default django gives you `{{ request.user.username }}` through out your templates. So you can call it on any templates

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the `usrnm` in your post request with `SUBMIT` on your `SecondPageSub`